# How to use subselects?

Tags: mysql, subquery

How can I rewrite this query using sub select query or any other method in MySQL? 
I am using 3 tables:

```html
SELECT i.resp_id as id
     , Count(1) 
FROM int_result i 
    JOIN response_set rs on i.response_set_id = rs.id 
    JOIN cx_store_child cbu on rs.cx_business_unit_id = cbu.child_bu_id
         AND cbu.business_unit_id = 30850
         AND rs.survey_id IN (5550512,5550516,5550521,5550520,5590351,5590384,5679615,5679646,5691634,5699259,5699266,5699270)
         AND i.q_id IN (52603091,52251250,52250724,52251333,52919541,52920117,54409178,54409806,54625102,54738933,54739117,54739221)
         AND rs.t >= '2017-08-30 00:00:00'
         AND rs.t <= '2017-09-30 00:00:00'
GROUP BY rs.cx_business_unit_id, i.a_id;
```

Comment: please specify the problem you face with the current code and what you are trying to achieve. Additionally, why do you have `COUNT(1)` in your select which will always return 1?

Comment: @ulferts, count(1) will return however many records qualified... 1 is just a place-holder for a found record.  would be same as count(*)

Comment: readability is one thing, optimize another.  Can you please describe exactly what you are TRYING to get.  You are grouping by fields not in your select statement, and getting count of records.  But what is the underlying thing you want.  Also, filtering by dates and explicit times?  what if the rs.t value is '2017-09-30 11:27:53'.  It would not be counted within the <= 2017-09-30 time declared.  Maybe you should go with rs.t < 2017-10-01 which includes 9/30 up to 11:59:59pm??

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is?

```
SELECT i.resp_id as id
     , Count(1) 
FROM int_result i, response_set rs, cx_store_child cbu
WHERE i.response_set_id = rs.id
         AND rs.cx_business_unit_id = cbu.child_bu_id
         AND cbu.business_unit_id = 30850
         AND rs.survey_id IN (5550512,5550516,5550521,5550520,5590351,5590384,5679615,5679646,5691634,5699259,5699266,5699270)
         AND i.q_id IN (52603091,52251250,52250724,52251333,52919541,52920117,54409178,54409806,54625102,54738933,54739117,54739221)
         AND rs.t >= '2017-08-30 00:00:00'
         AND rs.t <= '2017-09-30 00:00:00'
ORDER BY rs.cx_business_unit_id, i.a_id;
```